# Parsing a JSON Date/Time value using the Windows.Data.Json library in C#/WinRT project

Tags: c#, json, datetime, windows-runtime

I am receiving a JSON DateTime value that looks like the following: "/Date(1313438502992)/"

How can I convert it to the proper DateTime value in C# using the Windows.Data.Json library?

Using the following code results in an incorrect DateTime value being reported:

```
string dateValue = value.GetString();
//we get a value like "/Date(1313438502992)/"

dateValue = dateValue.Replace("/Date(", "");
dateValue = dateValue.Replace(")/", "");

var PublishDate = new System.DateTime(Convert.ToInt64(dateValue));
```

Not sure if the JSON encoder and the C# DateTime object use the same concept of the epoch. Any guidance would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I think "/Date(1313438502992)/" contains `DateTime` object as ticks & it returns me "01/02/0001 12:29:03", are you getting the same ?

Comment: Right-that is what I was seeing too, but the expected value was 8/15/2011 8:01:42 PM. Damir's insight that it calculates milliseconds since 1/1/1970 was the key: new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(millisecs);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON value should be [number of milliseconds since January 1st 1970 UTC](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2008/01/18/dates-and-json.aspx). Try the following code if it gives you the expected result:

```
var match = Regex.Match(dateValue, @"/Date\((?<millisecs>-?\d*)\)/");
var millisecs = Convert.ToInt64(match.Groups["millisecs"].Value);
var date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(millisecs);
```